# How to use scp to transfer files from WAN to LAN

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have machine A with a public IP address (addr_a), machine B within a LAN of private IP address(addr_b), the router of the LAN has a public IP address (addr_r). 
If I log into machine A by ssh from machine B, how can I use the command scp to copy files from machine A to machine B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you avoid logging in there? It would probably be better to run `scp` from `B` like

```
scp addr_a:foo/bar/baz .
```

If you absolutely cannot avoid it, you can either

- do a port forwarding from your router to `addr_b`,
- setup IPv6 and give `B` an own address,
- ssh from `B` to `A` with a remote port forwarding and then use this to get back.